# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt any alternative solution without installing mysqli drivers

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am all new to php . Now im on a project of adding / retrieving users tasks to database . While fetching tasks from database its return a error
**Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt:** . As per the result of my google search i found that i miss mysqli drivers in my server . Right now my server doesn't support installing these mysqli driver . here is my code

```
     public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tasks = $stmt->get_result();

    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}
```

So currently now i am looking for any alternative solutions .Any help is appreciable.

Comment: my server shows its mysqli enabled

Comment: i called customer care and they told me that i cant get msqli service because i'm on a shared hosting . so i need an alternative solution